# Equilibrium points for a system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got the following system:

$\dot x = -x+xy$

$\dot y = x-y -x^{2}-y^{3}$

And I want to find its fixed (equilibrium) points. So, I know I have to put $\dot x = 0$ and $\dot y = 0$, and for $\dot x = 0$ we have that $x(-1+y)=0$, that means, $\dot x = 0$ if $x=0$ and if $y=1$.

For $\dot y = x-y -x^2-y^3$ **is where the problem starts**. What is the technique to identify the $0$'s in this case?

I tried something like $x(1-x^2) = y(1+y^2)$, so the RHS is $0$ only for $y=0$, the LHS is $0$ for $x=1,x=-1,x=0.$ From this and by inspection I got that for $(x,y)=(1,0), (0,0), (-1,-1)$ but this was by inspection. So **how can I do this like rigorously? and how many fixed points should I find?**

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are only going to get one real fixed point at $(0,0)$, all the others have an imaginary $x$ or $y$ component, so those don't count. For example, for $y = 1$, you get $x = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm i \sqrt{7}\right)$. For $x = 0$, you also get $y = \pm i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align} \dot x &= -x+x y \\ \dot y &= x-y -x^{2}-y^{3} \end{align}$$

From the first equation, we get

$$-x+x y = 0 \implies x= 0, y = 1$$

For $x = 0$, in the second equation we get

$$y -y^{3} = 0 \implies y = 0, y = \pm i$$

We can only get real roots, so only the root $(x, y) = (0,0)$ counts.

For $y = 1$ in the second equation we get

$$-x^2 -x - 2 = 0 \implies x = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(1 \pm~ i \sqrt{7}\right)$$

Thus no roots from that.

We only have a single critical point.

We can draw a contour plot and see this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easier. You need to solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}
-x+xy = 0\\
x-y -x^{2}-y^{3} = 0
\end{cases}.$$

From the first equation, you get $x = 0$ and $y = 1.$
Using $x = 0,$ the second equation reads as:

$$0-y-0-y^3 = 0\Rightarrow y = 0.$$

Note that the previous equation has also $\pm i$ as solutions. This should be discarded if you are concerned with the study of **real-valued dynamical systems**.

Therefore, $[0, 0]$ is an equilibrium of your dynamical system.

On the other hand, for $y=1$, the second equation reads as:

$$x-1-x^2-1 = 0\Rightarrow x^2-x+2 = 0.$$ This equation has two complex conjugate solutions, namely:

$$x = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{7}}{2},$$

but these solutions are not feasible for real-valued systems.

In conclusion, **you system has only one real-valued equilibrium**, namely $[0, 0]$. Every nonreal solutions should be discarded.